# How to configure SSL on AppHarbor with ServiceStack.net web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, appharbor, servicestack

I am developing a set of web services using ServiceStack.net. I plan to host these services on Appharbor. I am fairly new to appharbor and cloud hosting in general.

I see that there is an interface within the dashboard to upload my SSL cert. What other configuration do I need to do to AppHarbor and/or my application to get this working properly?

Another note, My Servicestack services will be hosted within an MVC website. I will require all servicestack calls to be made over SSL and have implemented a request filter to check for this and throw a 403 if a non-secure call is attempted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are happy with SNI SSL support, no further configuration should be necessary. Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/915869) to determine whether a request is made with an SSL-encrypted connection.